# SharePoint List - Power Automate - Post updated item in a teams chat

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm facing an issue with the below flow, when I try to post a message in a chat.
The current flow reads the whole table but I would like to send only the last updated item.
[image]

Thank you in advance,
Andriana

Comment: Hi Andriana, I think you should use the "Get item" action in step 2 in stead of "Get ItemS". This way you will only get the item just created on your list. Perhaps this would also remove the need for the condition you have (in case the teams message should always fire on every item).

Comment: Hi Andrina, Query the Item in descending order by  Modified column, and Select the first row and hold data either in variable or compose statement. After this this step you will be able to process last modified items.

Comment: Thank you very much both for your replies. I used the "get item" action & moved the  "post message in a chat" out of the "apply to each" and it's working. Thank you again!